# Chains in the definition of relative homology group

Tags: algebraic-topology

In the definition of relative homology group, $C_n(X,A)$ is defined to be the quotient group $C_n(X)/C_n(A)$, while $X$ is a space and $A\subset X$ is a subspace of $X$. It means chains in $A$ should be taken trivial in $C_n(X,A)$. I was wondering how should we treat a singular chain like the one in the picture. It sits both in $A$ and $X-A$. Any ideas? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: For an interesting but familiar example, suppose $X$ is a connected, compact, orientable smooth $n$-manifold with non-empty boundary $A$. If $X$ is given a finite triangulation we can construct a chain $[X]\in C_n(X)$ which is essentially the sum of all the triangles. This is not a cycle since the boundary is contained in $A$, however its residue class in the relative chain group $[X,A]\in C_n(X, A)$ *is* a cycle, and in fact it is a generator of $H_n(X, A)\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if it doesn't sit entirely within $A$, it's not killed in the quotient.

In your situation (if I understand the drawing well), though, if you take its boundary for instance, you see that the bottom face will completely die, and the two other faces still live inbetween $A$ and $X\setminus A$.

$C_*(X,A)$ is exactly $C_*(X)$ except that the chains which lie *entirely* in $A$ die.

Comment: Does this mean this $\sigma$ could be an element of $C_*(X,A)$?

Comment: Well any element of $C_*(X)$ represents an element of $C_*(X,A)$, so yes

Comment: I saw in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book it says "The quotient $C_n(X,A)/C_n(A)$ could also be viewed as a subgroup of $C_n(X)$, the subgroup with basis the singular n-simplices $\sigma:\Delta^n \rightarrow X$ whose image is not contained in $A$." It seems there is a contradiction with Hatcher's words.

Comment: No, where's the contradiction ? You have a quotient map $C_n(X) \to C_n(X)/C_n(A) = C_n(X,A)$ and it happens that there is a subgroup $D$ such that the restriction of the projection $D\to C_n(X,A)$ is an isomorphism - there's no contradiction anywhere

Comment: I mean if $C_n(X,A)$ is generated by singular n-simplices whose image is not contained in $A$, how could the singular chain $\sigma$ I drew be an element of $C_*(X,A)$?

Comment: Well its image is not contained in $A$, is it ?

Comment: Yes.__________________

Comment: But even if its image were actually contained in $A$ : the fact that you can view it as generated by those simplices does *not* mean that the simplices whose image in $A$ can't be seen in $C_n(X,A)$ : they're just $0$ in that group. The subgroup point of view is one that can be useful, but there's also the quotient group point of view. It's interesting to have both in mind. That's why Hatcher says "also"

Comment: Ok, thanks.____